# Handling tables of messages and corresponding responses

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to figure out the best way to handle the relationship between two tables.  The first table stores new messages and the UID of the person who posted it;

```
+-----------+--------+-------------------+-----------+
| messageid | userid | subject           | message   |
+-----------+--------+-------------------+-----------+
|         1 |     70 | Subject           | Message   |
|         4 |     70 | Subject           | Message   |
|         5 |     63 | Subject           | Message   |
|         6 |     67 | Test              | Test      |
|         7 |     67 | Another test, yo' | Test, yo' |
+-----------+--------+-------------------+-----------+
```

The second table holds the list of recipients who have access to the respective messages.

```
+-----------+--------+
| messageid | userid |
+-----------+--------+
|         1 |     63 |
|         1 |     68 |
|         1 |     69 |
+-----------+--------+
```

My question is, because the messageid column in the recipients table relies on that same column in the messages table, what would be the best way to insert the information into the recipients table?  Messageid is created at the time that the message is posted, so would I query the messages table for a messageid, turn that into a variable and use that variable to insert into the recipients table?  Or is there a more practical way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're creating the `` `message.messageId `` column values using an autoincrement column, you can use the MySQL `LAST_INSERT_ID()` function to retrieve its value in a subsequent statement.

So you could do something like this:

```
 INSERT INTO message (userid, subject, message) VALUES (70, 'Subject', 'Message');
 SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

Retrieve that value in your program.  Then do a sequence of

```
 INSERT INTO recipient (messageid, userid) VALUES (value, userid);
```

If for some reason you need to do this without retrieving and using the `LAST_INSERT_ID()` in your client program, you can do this sequence of SQL statements.

```
INSERT INTO message (userid, subject, message) VALUES (?, ?, ?);

INSERT INTO recipient (messageid, userid)
SELECT a.messageid, b.userid
  FROM (
         SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() AS messageid
       ) AS a
  JOIN (
       SELECT ? AS userid
       UNION ALL
       SELECT ? AS userid
       UNION ALL
       SELECT ? AS userid
  ) AS b;
```

The `UNION ALL` and `JOIN` allow the insertion of a bunch of userids in one SQL statement, all with the same value from `LAST_INSERT_ID()`.

Comment: Hi, Ollie.  So, if there are multiple write happening at the same time to the table, how does mysql know that I'm trying to get the messageID from the respective transaction?  If three people are doing inserts at the same time, wouldn't this cause an issue?

Comment: `LAST_INSERT_ID()` returns the latest autoincrement value generated *on the current connection.*  So it's entirely robust in situations where multiple clients or multiple threads are using their own connections to update the data base. It is *extremely* unlikely that more than one thread is using a single connection, because most client library connection objects aren't even slightly thread-safe.

Comment: Interesting.  Wow, that sounds incredibly useful.  I'm glad I asked.  Thank you, Ollie.

Comment: Ollie, last question.  I'm assuming that I'd be running last_insert_id() in a separate mysqli_query php statement than the one I'm using for the insertion, correct?

Comment: Same connection as the `INSERT INTO messages`, but different statement.

Comment: Ollie,  my statements are in the same form and look like this;
mysqli_query($db_conn,"insert into feed_messages (userid, subject, message) values ('$useridvalue', '$subject', '$message');") 
or die("".mysql_error());

$messageid = mysqli_query($db_conn,"select last_insert_id();") or die("".mysql_error());

Aren't these technically two different connections?

Comment: It seems they all use the same $db_conn value, so they're all the same connection.